The meaning of "sharp" in "sharp sweetness"

Go for gold in the kitchen with our Olympic Games inspired menu! Tuck
into this Creamy Chicken à la Normande whilst you're watching Paris
2024 for a winning dinnertime. Cooking "à la Normande" means "in the
style of Normandy", resulting in a creamy sauce with tart apples and a
hint of sharp sweetness. HIGH PROTEIN - Protein contributes to the
maintenance of muscle mass.

Creamy Chicken à La Normande
What does sharp mean? The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary gives the following definition of "sharp":

9 ★ ​strong and slightly bitter

, but I don't think this meaning matches the meaning of sharp.

Do you know what 'tart apples' are? Not ones suitable for baking in tarts, but ones with a hint of sourness in their flavour. Sharp sweetness means sweetness with a refreshing hint of a contrasting flavour.

@KateBunting - yes. Also the crème fraîche will add a touch of sourness. The text quoted in the OP is clumsy. It seems to suggest that "à la Normande" means all of 'a creamy sauce with tart apples and a hint of sharp sweetness'.

@KateBunting I knew what "tart apples" were, but the meaning of "sharp sweetness" that you've given didn't occur to me, because I had unconsciously assumed that "sharp" was synonymous with "strong". Thank you very much, Kate Bunting.

In fact, the recipe writer gets a nul for French, because you don't capitalise adjectives of nationality, region, or origin, so it should be à la normande. But note that you would write poulet à la Kiev because Kiev is a proper noun, but poulet à la kiévienne is an alternative. Even Wikipedia gets far breton wrong.

The Cambridge Dictionary defines sharp as "sour in taste", with acid as a synonym. It further offers lemons (which contain citric acid) as an example. Apples (especially cooking or cider apples) contain malic acid.
Sharp does not qualify sweetness, but is meant to be treated separately. The five mouth-flavour elements are sweet, salt, acid, bitter and umami. Sharp sweetness refers to a pleasing contrast between sweet and acid.

Thank you very much, JavaLatte. I didn't know that "umami" is an English word.

It has only entered the English language recently - in the present century, I would say.

@Kaguyahime Umami was coined by Kikunae Ikeda in 1908, but the word was first used in English in 1979.  Before then, scientists believed that there were only four mouth-flavour elements.

The mustard also adds acid, probably more than the apples (unless they're a very tart variety; the recipe doesn't specify).

@WeiwenNg The recipe is "à la normande", a reference to the fact that Normandy is famous for cider and calvados. Mustard is slightly less acidic than cider apples, and is probably used in much smaller quantities.

@Kaguyahime The more traditional English word that is sometimes used as a synonym for 'umami' is 'savory' but that is also the name of an herb that was, from what I recall reading, essentially synonymous with 'flavor' prior to the influx of spices to Europe.  'Umami' is more specific to the taste of glutamate.

"Sharp does not qualify sweetness" I'm willing to accept this but my first thought was that 'sharp sweetness' implied a strong initial sweetness that fades quickly as opposed to a lingering taste of sweetness.

@Jimmyjames " strong initial sweetness"... that might be a valid explanation for something that is 98% sugar, but... cider apples? Nah.  The Cambridge Dictionary defines savoury as "salty or spicy"... umami is completely different. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/savoury

@JavaLatte A 'savory pie' generally refers to a meat or cheese pie.  Umami is the flavor of glutamate which is found in meats, cheeses, and seafoods as well as in some vegetables such as tomatoes. That people didn't understand that there was a fifth taste doesn't change the fact that they were using this word to describe foods with it.

@JavaLatte For reference here's NYT article: "Yes, MSG, the Secret Behind the Savor" or "Monosodium Glutamate (MSG): The Controversial Savory Flavor Enhancer" or an MSG sauce used worldwide named 'Savor'

Quoting a slightly older reference; "Ye are the salt of the earth: but if the salt have lost its savor, wherewith shall it be salted?" King James Bible, Matthew 5:13. Maybe it's a BrE/AmE thing.

The strong part of the definition the OP has quoted is valid.
M+W sense 5a1 definition for sharp says

affecting the senses or sense organs intensely: such as
a
(1)
: having a strong odor or flavor

M+W
